# npm install throws 407 error with HTML

Tags: node.js, npm, http-proxy

when I run `npm install` I get a very long error saying `error parsing json` and continues with the source code of a HTML page that tells me I have a '407 Proxy Authentication Required' error.

The full log can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/T7a4zuYK

this is what `npm config list` returns:

```
; cli configs
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
user-agent = "npm/1.4.28 node/v0.10.34 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\PV01054\.npmrc
https-proxy = "http://localhost:3128/"
proxy = "http://localhost:3128/"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\PV01054\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Repos\randstad-nl
; HOME = C:\Users\PV01054
; 'npm config ls -l' to show all defaults.
```

Comment: Are you really what your proxy doesn't demand authentication? May be you need set login/password for proxy: http://superuser.com/questions/347476/how-to-install-npm-behind-authentication-proxy-on-windows

Comment: For some reason, adding my username and password to my https-proxy and proxy seemed to work. A colleague of mine didn't need to do that.